# How do i get MX records without mail server on my own?

Tags: ssl, https, smtp, mail-server, mx-record

I'm trying to make my website into HTTPS.

This website is made up of plain HTML pages.

But the problem is When I need to validate that I am the owner of the website, All the SSL providers wants to send an email to my mail server.

They got email list from my domain which are webmaster@example.com, hostmaster@example.com, and postmaster@example.com.

But I do not have a mail server nor above mail addresses.

Furthermore, My domain service provider doesn't offer an email server.

Is there any easy way to solve this issue without having mail server?

Answer (score 1):

**Creating a custom domain email address with Gmail**

let’s assume you own the domain **example.tld** and your name is **Ali**. You could easily set up **ali@example.tld** as your email address. Remember, you need to own your own domain!

OK, Lets start:

1. Go to the Google Apps Gmail page and click the button that says "Get
   Started".
2. Enter your information and click "Next"
3. Select the first option "Use a domain name I have already
   purchased", enter the domain you want to use and then click "Next".
4. This step is to create your account. Complete the form and then
   click "Accept and signup".
5. Now that your account has been created, we can start the domain
   verification process. Click the "Start Setup button.
6. Click the "Verify Domain" button.
7. Since example.tld is not hosted on NetworkSolutions.com so Click the
   "No" button.
8. Select "Other" from the drop down list and then click "Begin
   verification".
9. Select the "Alternate methods" tab and then select the "HTML file
   upload". Download the generated HTML verification file and save it
   to your Desktop. Wait, ***Do not click verify!*** You should first
   upload the verification file to your web root using ftp. Then go
   back and click the "Verify" button.
10. The final step of this process is adding the Gmail MX Records to
     your domain. Google provides their own mail servers, which you can
     read about [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125). Switching your MX Records to the ones
     provided on their page differs depending on your hosting service.

***Congratulations! You are Done!***

Remember, DNS changes may take a few hours for them to take effect across the Internet.

Good luck,